Gradle doesn't understand implementation "package name" in build.gradle
I have code that uses the package org.firstinspires.ftc:RobotCore. I am trying to import it using Gradle, but it gives me this error:
:fancytelemetry:main: Could not resolve org.firstinspires.ftc:RobotCore:9.1.0. It tells me to declare the repository providing the artifact, but I've already done that in ftNEW/fancytelemetry/build.gradle. RobotCore is in maven central.
I'm relatively new to Gradle, and I have no clue why this is happening. All the sample code I can find says the exact same thing but it errors for me.
Here is my file structure:

Here is the ftNEW/fancytelemetry/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

//apply from: '../build.common.gradle'
apply from: '../build.dependencies.gradle'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.firstinspires.ftc/RobotCore")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.firstinspires.ftc', name: 'RobotCore', version: '9.1.0'
}

The ftNEW/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "java"
}

version "1.0"

And the ftNEW/build.dependencies.gradle:
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google() // Needed for androidx
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.firstinspires.ftc:RobotCore:9.2.0'
}

I'm using Gradle 8.7.

it seems you are not applying java plugin in your main build.gradle script, so Gradle will not understand what  implementation configuration means.

According to this "Maven Central" I found by googleing, it recommends implementation group: 'org.firstinspires.ftc', name: 'RobotCore', version: '9.1.0' for the dependency.

@markspace It gives a slightly different error now:
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [{group=org.firstinspires.ftc, name=RobotCore, version=9.1.0}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

@M.Ricciuti I have tried that and updated the post to include the new error I got, would you mind looking at it? Thank you!

@isaiahday i think you are using an old version of gradle where implementation configuration was not already available, this is a common error, there are tons of questions with error message Could not find method implementation . If you are using the Gradle Wrapper , which is the recommended way, make sure to set the correct version ( https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) ; if using a preinstall version of Gradle, check version with gradle -version

@M.Ricciuti Hi, I updated to gradle 8.10 (the latest version) and I still get this error. Also,my error message is not "Could not find method implementation". I had that error a while ago but managed to fix it by updating to gradle 8.7. My error is :fancytelemetry:main: Could not resolve org.firstinspires.ftc:RobotCore:9.1.0. Thank you!
